# Is it possible to schedule a Retry for a SQL job instead of its Step components whenever one of the Steps fail?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-job

I am using `SQL Server 2014` and I have a `SQL` job (an `SSIS` package which contains 11 steps) which has been scheduled to run on a daily basis at a specific time.

I  know one can schedule each step to attempt a retry whenever that step fails. However, is there a way to configure a retry for the whole `SQL` job whenever the job fails at any step during the process? That is, if say, the job fails at Step 8, the whole job is run again from Step 1.

Comment: What happens if it fails forever?

Comment: If the job had one step, and the SSIS package took care of its own error handling/retrying (using a for loop or suchlike) then the retry would be equally simple -- just retry that one step if it fails.

Answer (score 1):

The *tidiest* solution I can think of would be creating an error handling Step in your Job which will be executed when any other step fails (change the On Failure action of all other steps to jump to this one) and managing the job's schedule to trigger again on the following minute, after the job ends. This way you will see the execution history of the job at the agent.

You will have to keep in mind recurrent failures, I doubt you want the job to be repeating itself indefinitely.

To configure the job to trigger, you can add a Schedule that fires every minute and enable/disable it when necessary. The job won't fire if it's already running.